# My android app crashes while sharing a gif

Tags: java, android, crash, android-imageview, gif

I created a meme share app that takes a random meme from Reddit in Image view and the user has the option to share the meme through other apps. The share function works good with jpg, png, etc file types except gif. **The gif appears in the imageView but as soon as I click the share button the app crashes**. This only happens in the gif file type

My share Function code. The function name is **shareMeme**.

```
private void shareImageandText(Bitmap bitmap) {
        Uri uri = getmageToShare(bitmap);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

        // putting uri of image to be shared
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

        // adding text to share
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hey! Checkout this cool meme on Reddit");

        // Add subject Here
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Try Meme Lelo");

        // setting type to image
        intent.setType("image/*");

        // calling startactivity() to share
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Via"));
    }

    // Retrieving the url to share
    private Uri getmageToShare(Bitmap bitmap) {
        File imagefolder = new File(getCacheDir(), "images");
        Uri uri = null;
        try {
            imagefolder.mkdirs();
            File file = new File(imagefolder, "shared_image.png");
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, outputStream);
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.akki.memelelo.fileprovider", file);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return uri;
    }


    public void shareMeme(View view) {
        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) memeImageView.getDrawable();
        Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
        shareImageandText(bitmap);
}
```

**Logcat - Red Lines Error Msg**

2021-07-02 15:04:26.238 9953-9953/com.akki.memelelo E/AndroidRuntime: **FATAL EXCEPTION: main**
Process: com.akki.memelelo, PID: 9953
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:414)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448) 
at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119) 
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425) 
at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.gif.GifDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable
at com.akki.memelelo.MainActivity.shareMeme(MainActivity.java:148)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409) 
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448) 
at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119) 
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425) 
at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)

2021-07-02 15:04:28.797 7519-7836/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox E/sb.v.u.LiteSuggestSourc: On-device lite suggest model loading error.

2021-07-02 15:04:29.025 7519-7745/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox E/MDD: DownloadProgressMonitor: Can't find file group for uri: android://com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/files/sharedminusonemodule/shared/SharedMinusOneData.pb.tmp

2021-07-02 15:06:49.119 207-211/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: **Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup34: **Permission denied****
2021-07-02 15:06:49.125 207-211/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: **Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup35: **Permission denied****

Comment: Please share to logcat for the crash

Comment: Also, **always** use a concrete MIME type when you are **sending** content to another app. You are using a wildcard, so the receiving app does not know what type of image this is.

Comment: So you're getting GIF as bitmap and compressing it to PNG?

Comment: @Darkman, I guess I'm doing so. I am a beginner in Android Development and I wrote this code with the help of the internet. Can you suggest me some changes?

Comment: @CommonsWare, I am a beginner in Android Development. Can you suggest to me how to do so?

Answer (score 1):

```
BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) memeImageView.getDrawable();
```

Here you are casting GifDrawable to BitmapDrawable which is leading to crash.
For getting Image (as Bitmap Object) this works, but you have to handle GIF separately. possible check what is loaded in ImageView and share content accordingly.

For sharing GIF, save GIF on Internal/External storage and share it's URI with:

```
"image/gif"
```

Like this:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("image/gif");
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(sharingGifFile);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Emoji"));
```